# How to use the XMLAGG tag, getting from clause not found

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use the XMLAGG to an alternative for listagg due to the size constraints of 4000 char. but my code doesn't work and complains that from clause isn't present where it should be.
any help?

```
SELECT key_id,RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,source_name,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY entity_key_id).GetClobVal(),',') AS source_name
,RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,CASE WHEN upper(description) LIKE '%CC%' THEN substr(description, (instr(upper(description),'CC',1) ),length(description) )
                        ELSE NULL  END,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY key_id).GetClobVal(),',')
                        --OVER (PARTITION BY tsk.entity_key_id)
FROM task
WHERE
 task.level_code = 'XYZ' and task.TASK_TYPE_CODE in ('ABC', 'CEF')
 ;
```

Comment: These are oracle functions, so the sql-server tag probably shouldn't be on this (unless you're trying to solve it in either)

Comment: Split it into simpler parts and see what the problem is.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't throw that error. Which version of Oracle are you using? And which client, in case the commented-out line is somehow confusing it?

Comment: OK, you'd only get that error it you uncommented that line; but it isn't clear what that is supposed to do. Are `key_id` and `entity_key_id` actually the same and you changed names inconsistently? If so you just need to `group by entity_key_id` instead I think.

Comment: Found the solution for this, it worked. By adding a group by entity_key